# Replace value with API value in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am listing a bunch of JSON objects to a view, but only it's category ID is included. Not the name, which I need to display. I have to make a separate `$http` call to process which items match. Values will not render to view. Code:

```
$scope.cardCategories = function(id) {
  angular.forEach($scope.categoryFilter, function(category, index){
    if (category.id == id) {
      //console.log(category.name);
      return category.name;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  })
}
```

value inside a simplified ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="topic in latest">
    {{cardCategories(topic.category_id)}}
</div>
```

I have also attempted to write this as a filter, but the value will not display. Console shows the matches. My suspicion is that I have to process the original `latest` array. Thanks.

```
.filter('cardCategories', function($rootScope, $state){
return function(catId) {
  if (catId !== undefined && $rootScope.cardCategories) {
    angular.forEach($rootScope.cardCategories.categories, function(category, index){
      if (category.id == catId.category_id) {
        return category.name;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    })
  }
}
})
```

View:

`{{topic.category_id | cardCategories}}`

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(category.name);` in your `forEach` loop?

Comment: The correct category name.

Comment: there is a set statement on $scope after return... in first code... please fix that

Comment: thanks, meant to leave that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `return` statement in the `forEach` callback function will not return a value from the `$scope.cardCategories`, it returns *something* from the callback you provided to `forEach` (and angular happily ignores it). Try something like this:

```
$scope.cardCategories = function(id) {
  var i = $scope.categoryFilter.length; // assuming it's an array 

  while(i--) {
   if($scope.categoryFilter[i].id === id) {
     return $scope.categoryFilter[i].name;
   }
  }
};
```

Also -- there's no way to break (stop early) an `angular.forEach` loop, so for performance reasons it's better to avoid it if you're locating something inside an array/object.

Comment: there were cases where a match wasn't made so I needed to check its existence. I tried adding an `else` and it wouldn't return the value. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the `forEach` loop doesn't do a `return` if the current iteration doesn't match the ID you passed in.

Take out the `else` condition from your if statement

```
$scope.cardCategories = function(id) {
  angular.forEach($scope.categoryFilter, function(category, index){
    if (category.id == id) {
      return category.name;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This probably would have worked also, but am going with the `while`  statement for performance. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ZappB. Performance is the same.  They are both linear in nature

Comment: In both solutions, the `else` breaks it. why is this?

Comment: @ZappB. When you run `return` inside of a function, the function immediately exits.  So unless the first property of the object you run the function on has the id you are looking for, the function will return `undefined`